# Rocket universe2 stop console messages in vb.net console application

Tags: dns, console, universe, rocket

I have a vb.net console application that uses a Rocket Universe 2 database as a DSN. I can connect to the database and query it, but the console always displays progress messages for each fetch. Querying from my local Sql Server does not cause any messages to appear in the console window. I believe that the constant posting of messages to the console takes up a lot of I/O time and there should be an option to have it not display progress in the console window. Any help?

Comment: Could you sanitize and post your code, please? I am not able to replicate it in my console app.

Comment: Here is a small sample of the code that opens the connection to the remote database using the DSN created for SQL SERVER. Below the code is the output to the console immediately upon executing the calls to the remote host database. The console window does not output any progress from my local Sql Server database interraction. I hope that you can glean something from this:

Comment: Dim ConnString as String = "Data Source=Sagitta;Initial Catalog=XXXXX;User id = YYYYY;password=ZZZZ"
 Dim SagConnOdbc As New odbcconnection(ConnString)
 SagConnOdbc.Open()
 Dim SagSelect as String = "SELECT * FROM CLIENTS"

 Dim dtb As New DataSet
 Using dad As New OdbcDataAdapter(SagSelect, SagConnOdbc)
     dad.Fill(dtb)
 End Using
 
------OUTPUT TO CONSOLE WINDOW --------------------- 
   
User name:     YYYYY
User password: ZZZZ
Database name: Dddd.sql
Debug level:   2
ODBCSvc flags: -D -FC:\U2\UniDK\Config\uci.config
Request name: GetRequests.  Full request:

Comment: I have never been particularly happy with the ODBC connection using the method you suggested. I have switched to using the Rocket U2 Toolkit for .Net which should be available to you if you are under support. http://www.rocketsoftware.com/products/rocket-u2/rocket-u2-toolkit-net With this you can use the U2DataAdapter object instead of the ODBC and it does not exhibit the behavior you have.

Comment: I will check with our support people and see if the toolkit is available for us, as it should be. Thanks for your response!

Comment: It appears that the UniVerse 2 server has an error log for the server and each ODBC connection and it sends messages that are getting picked up at my console. I need a way to stop the messages to the console. These messages appear in another forum but the symptoms are the same:

Comment: See this thread: http://www.yqcomputer.com/257_711_1.htm